# How to display of results in Google Forms after deleting some response?

Tags: google-forms

I have collected some data using Google Form that are visualized by Google Form in histogram and pie chart. Now I want to circulate URL of same Google Form. But I want it should show the visualization of new responses not clubbing previous and current results.

Answer (score -1):

i know this is an old post but this answer is for anyone else looking for the same solution to a similar problem quite recently.

Heres a simple workaround solution:

collate the correct data you want to display onto a new sheet - i.e. all your new responses - make your own histograms/ graphs / pivots  or charts etc - save these all onto one single sheet & then simply publish that single read only anylitical data sheet to the web & share that link with your participants.

Heres how to Publish your single read only google sheet webpage :

lets say for example you want to share the form responses data or you have made your own analytical summary charts & pivots & graphs based off that data you received on one particular sheet & you would like to share that analysis sheet publically

so for example i want to share just the form responses sheet with my particapiants, heres what i will do

on the main menue of the google sheet linked to the form responses

click on "file"

click on "publish to web"

You get two options - a public link which you can share - or the embed code

on the link section

click on the drop down & select "form responses 1"

Click on "Publish"

You will get a publically sharable weblink of just the form responses sheet that will auto update evry 5 minutes, like wise you can share any of the other sheets aswell not just the form responses sheet.

it basically converts any of the sheets you would like to publically share into a single 'read only' simple webpage.

be careful though - if you select "entire document" your whole google sheet will be shared with all its sheets publically visible to anyone with the link

On the second dropdown below " Published content & settings"

Select the same sheet name as you selected in the first drop down "form responses 1" or select any other sheets that you want to share aswell simentensously

click on "publish"

When you want to stop sharing your sheet or sheets just click "stop publishing"